# My items page is fetching the items multiple times

Tags: node.js, react-native

I have created a page to fetch the items in a subcategory. It suppose to fetch 6 items, then if the user swipes up, it fetches another 6 items. If less than 6 items available, it should not fetch the same item multiple times.

Currently there are two items but it fetches them continuously.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback, useRef } from 'react';
import {
View,
Text,
FlatList,
Image,
TouchableOpacity,
StyleSheet,
RefreshControl,
} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
const ItemsPage = ({ navigation, route }) => {
const { subCategoryName } = route.params;
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);
const [allItemsFetched, setAllItemsFetched] = useState(false);
const initialFetch = useRef(true);

const fetchItems = async () => {
  if (initialFetch.current) {
    initialFetch.current = false;
  } else {
    setLoading(true);
  }
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:5000/api/items/bySubCategory?subCategory=${subCategoryName}&limit=6&page=${page}`
    );
    console.log('Fetched items:', response.data);
    if (response.data.length === 0) {
      setLoading(false);
      setAllItemsFetched(true);
      return;
    }
    const newItems = response.data.map((item) => {
      const existingItem = items.find((i) => i._id === item._id);
      if (existingItem) {
        return existingItem;
      } else {
        return {
          ...item,
          uid: item._id,
        };
      }
    });
    setItems((prevItems) => {
      return [...prevItems, ...newItems];
    });
    setPage((prevPage) => prevPage + 1);
    setLoading(false);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching items:', error);
    console.log('Error details:', error.toJSON());
    setLoading(false);
  }
};


useEffect(() => {
fetchItems();
}, []);
const handleLoadMore = () => {
if (!loading && !allItemsFetched) {
fetchItems();
}
};
const RenderItemComponent = React.memo(({ item, onPress }) => {
console.log('Rendering item:', item);
console.log('Item image URI:', item.images[0]);
return (
<TouchableOpacity
style={styles.itemContainer}
onPress={() => onPress(item._id)}
>
<Image source={{ uri: item.images[0] }} style={styles.itemImage} />
</TouchableOpacity>
);
});
const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
return (
<RenderItemComponent
item={item}
onPress={(itemId) => navigation.navigate('ItemPage', { itemId })}
/>
);
};
const onRefresh = useCallback(async () => {
setRefreshing(true);
setPage(1);
setItems([]);
initialFetch.current = true;
await fetchItems();
setRefreshing(false);
}, []);
return (
<View style={styles.container}>
<Text>Items for {subCategoryName}</Text>
<FlatList
data={items}
renderItem={renderItem}
keyExtractor={(item) => item.uid}
numColumns={2}
onEndReached={handleLoadMore}
onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
refreshControl={
<RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
}
/>
</View>
);
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
},
itemContainer: {
flex: 1,
padding: 15,
},
itemImage: {
width: '100%',
    height: 300,
    borderRadius: 23,
  },
});

export default ItemsPage;
```

I have tried several methods and this is my first application